# Python Temperature conversion MVC style: why am I getting "TypeError: buttonPressed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

newbie-wanna-be python-programmer here. I had a homework assignment (that I couldn't get) and now that the class is over, I feel comfortable asking for help here. I'm still really curious about this error and what I'm doing wrong... I'm sure it's related to how the CONTROLLER and the VIEW are referring to each other, but I this error is beyond my  understanding. I've been stuck on this for about three days. I could really use help- because I really want to understand python and MVC.

Please see screen cap below for context.

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: buttonPressed() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

VIEW: myFrame.py

```
"""writing event handlers"""

import tkinter
import glue
class MyFrame(tkinter.Frame): #creates window for controls in an object made
                              #from a class called "tkinter.Frame" 
    """
    Class myFrame is a tkinter.Frame...
    It contains two buttons, two entry areas, and four labels:
    one button a converter;
    one button quits the program;
    one entry is for celsius;
    one entry is for fahrenheit;
    and the labels prompt user for input, and label the entry values as needed.
    """

    def __init__(self, controller):
        """
        places the controls on the frame
        """
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self) #initilizes the superclass 
        self.pack()  #required for the buttons to show up properly.
        self.controller = glue.Controller #saves ref to controller to call methods on
                                          #contoller object when user generates events

#Fahrenheit Input Prompt
        self.fahrenheitLabel = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.fahrenheitLabel["text"] = ("Enter Fahrenheit Value:")
        self.fahrenheitLabel.pack({"side":"left"})

#Fahrenheit Entry Space
        self.fahrenheitEntrySpace = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.fahrenheitEntrySpace == self.fahrenheitEntrySpace.insert(1, "0")  
        self.fahrenheitEntrySpace.pack({"side":"left"})

#Fahrenheit Value label
        self.fahrenheitLabel = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.fahrenheitLabel["text"] = ("Fahrenheit Degrees")
        self.fahrenheitLabel.pack({"side":"left"})

#Converter button 
        self.convertButton=tkinter.Button(self)
        self.convertButton["text"]= "Convert"
        self.convertButton["command"]=self.controller.buttonPressed
        # an object that remembers both self and reply when later called
        self.convertButton.pack({"side":"left"})       

#Quit button
        self.quitButton = tkinter.Button(self)
        self.quitButton["text"] = "Press\nhere to\n***QUIT***"
        self.quitButton["command"] = self.quit
        #the statement above attaches the event handler
        #self.quit() to the quit button
        self.quitButton.pack({"side":"right"})

#Celsius Value label
        self.celsiusLabel = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.celsiusLabel["text"] = ("Celsius Degrees")
        self.celsiusLabel.pack({"side":"right"})

#Celsius Entry Space
        self.celsiusEntrySpace = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.celsiusEntrySpace["text"] == self.celsiusEntrySpace.insert(1, "0")
        self.celsiusEntrySpace.pack({"side":"right"})


#Celsius Input Prompt
        self.celsiusLabel = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.celsiusLabel["text"] = ("Enter Celsius Value:")
        self.celsiusLabel.pack({"side":"right"})

#Test program
if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    view = MyFrame() #puts the frame onto the user's screen.
    view.mainloop()
    root.destroy()
```

MODEL: counter.py

```
import tkinter


class Convert: #the MODEL

    '''
    class counter is the MODEL for a simple program that exemplifies
    the MODEL/VIEW/CONTROLLER architecture.

    It mostly just maintains two formulas that convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
    and Celsius to Fahrenheit each time the f2C() or c2F methods are called.

    in a real MVC app, the MODEL would contain all the business logic.
    Note that the model never contains a reference to the VIEW.
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.fahrenheitEntrySpace = 0
        self.celsiusEntrySpace = 0

    def convertTempF2C(self):
        fahrenheit = fahrenheitEntrySpace.get()
        if fahrenheit != 0.0:
            celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
        else:
            celsius = -17.7777778 

    def convertTempC2F(self):
        celsius = celsiusEntrySpace.get()
        if celsius != 0.0:
            fahrenheit = (celsius *  9.0/5.0 + 32)          
        else:
            fahrenheit = 32

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.counter)
```

CONTROLLER: "glue.py"

```
import tkinter

import myFrame #the VIEW

import counter #the MODEL

class Controller:

    """
    The CONTROLLER for an app that follows the MODEL/VIEW/CONTROLLER architecture.
    When the user presses a button on the VIEW,
    this controller calls the appropriate methods in the model.
    The controller handles all the communication between the model and the view.
    """

    def __init__(self):

        """
        This starts the TK framework up;
        instantiates the model;
        instantiates the VIEW;
        and states the event loop that waits for the user to press a button on the view
        """
        root = tkinter.Tk() #This starts the TK framework up;
        self.model = counter.Convert() #instantiates the model
        self.view = myFrame.MyFrame(self) #instantiates the VIEW
        self.view.mainloop() # states event loop waits for user to press button on view
        root.destroy() #lets user quit

    def buttonPressed(self):

        """
        Convert F --> C
        """

        self.model.convertTempF2C(self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.get)
        #MODEL creates new celsius temp from(fahrenheit input) 

        self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.pop()
        #replaces VIEW's old default celsius value

        self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.insert(self.model.celsius)
        #and insert's MODEL's newly converted (celsius) value

        """
        Convert C --> F
        """

        self.model.convertTempC2F(self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.get)
        #MODEL creates new fahrenheit temp from  (celsius input)

        self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.pop() 
        #replaces VIEW's old default 0 fahrenheit value 

        self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.insert(self.model.fahrenheit)
        #and insert's MODEL's newly converted (fahrenheit) value

if __name__=="__main__":
    c = Controller()
```

## screen cap

[http://imgur.com/pAQc3Zw](https://imgur.com/pAQc3Zw) <-- link to screen cap (I can't post w/o 10 reputation.

Edit:
After fixing the self ref loop, I ran into other issues as seen here:
[Python MVC architecture Temperature Conversion: Why am I getting "NameError: global name 'view' is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276395/python-mvc-architecture-temperature-conversion-why-am-i-getting-nameerror-glo)

Comment: Please take a minute to [format your post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I tried. I can't post with an error message about indenting, and since the error message doesn't tell me which part needs to be indented, I had trouble finding the proper part- so this was the only way, that I found, that I could actually post. ie. my horrible formatting isn't from neglect- I'm just unable to format it well in a way that will be accepted. Apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MyFrame.__init__`, you're saving a reference to the `Controller` class:

```
self.controller = glue.Controller
```

But you're not actually creating an instance of `Controller`, which means `Controller.__init__` is never called. That's probably not what you meant to do.

It also means that when you do this:

```
    self.convertButton["command"]=self.controller.buttonPressed
```

You're really saying

```
    self.convertButton["command"]= glue.Controller.buttonPressed
```

Which means you're making an *unbound* method the callback for `convertButton`. Unbound means that the method isn't bound to a particular instance of `Controller`, which means `self` won't implicitly be passed to it - hence the error you're getting. Your program is creating a `Controller` instance when it starts, and that is what's calling `MyFrame.__init__`. You're actually 99% of the way to do things properly - you're passing the `Controller` instance to `MyFrame.__init__`:

```
    self.view = myFrame.MyFrame(self) #instantiates the VIEW
```

So now all you need to do is assign that instance to `self.controller`Controller.**init**`:

```
def __init__(self, controller):
    """
    places the controls on the frame
    """
    tkinter.Frame.__init__(self)
    self.pack()
    self.controller = controller  # NOT glue.Controller
```

Comment: Hi Dano! Thank you so much for the feedback! So, are you saying I basically just need to replace self.controller = glue.Controller with self.controller = glue.Controller() ? 

When I did that, things got a little crazy... imgur.com/8a7gcxO <-- screenshot for context It just repeats: errors in lines 27, 25, and a few others (text is limited, please see screen cap for more info) Thank you for your reply! It adds a level of clarity I was missing regarding MVC! 

I'm guessing the rest of what is wrong is just my messed up programming :/

Comment: @lilmookie Ah, you have a circular reference - the `Controller.__init__` creates an instance of `MyFrame`, and `MyFrame.__init`` creates an instance of `Controller`. So they just end up calling each other over and over until you hit the recursion limit. I apologize for not catching that before. Oddly enough, you were *almost* doing this properly - you were already passing the `Controller` instance to `MyFrame.__init__` you just weren't using it!

Comment: It's starting to make sense. I changed myframe (the view) init from self.controller = _Glue.Controller()_ to self.controller = **controller** and now I'm getting errors that make more sense to me.

I'll see what I can do, and hopefully post a completed version of this for the site's future reference for people like me :p

Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: The (much nicer) error in question:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1482, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\code\Assignment 6\glue.py", line 37, in buttonPressed
    self.model.convertTempF2C(self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.get)
TypeError: convertTempF2C() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given